# Would it be possible to add default methods to Comparable without breaking Java?

Tags: java, comparable, default-method

I was thinking of proposing a feature request to add default methods called:

```
default boolean greaterThan(T o) {
    return compareTo(o) > 0;
}

default boolean smallerThan(T o) {
    return compareTo(o) < 0;
}

default boolean atLeast(T o) {
    return compareTo(o) >= 0;
}

default boolean atMost(T o) {
    return compareTo(o) <= 0;
}
```

to the `Comparable` interface as it would make the code much more readable - in my opinion.

However, I'm wondering if that would break code. Is there any code such as Lambda's that would break if we add default methods?

If I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33108540/589259) correctly I would assume that Lambda's would at least remain working, as long as they won't try to call the new methods, but I'm not sure. And I don't know if there could be any (obvious) other issues.

Please, no discussion about the possible feature request itself.

Comment: Something that can happen: https://stuartmarks.wordpress.com/2020/09/22/incompatibilities-with-jdk-15-charsequence-isempty/

Comment: Might be helpful: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.5.6

Comment: Thanks guys, read both. Makes sense that it could cause issues, but I don't see them as terribly dangerous either. It would have to be a pretty weird method to cause naming clashes at source level, but yeah, you never know.

Comment: @Slaw why not make that an answer? imho, coupled with an example, it directly answers it.

Comment: @Eugene Not sure I understand it thoroughly enough to give an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, @BasilBourque's answer is misleading, even though it quotes useful entities.

There is no way this feature will be introduced by way of a subinterface. SortedMap/NavigableMap is **not** applicable: The `default` mechanism was not around when `NavigableMap` was introduced!

At this point, it may be worthwhile to introduce some or all of the methods in `NavigableMap` as `default` methods in `SortedMap`, with implementations that work on sortedmaps and which will automatically end up getting overridden by any Map impls that implemented NavigableMap already (as they have overridden all of those in their impl).

However, it means that 'Hey, look at NavigableMap which is analogous to SortedMap just like what you want to do to Comparable' is **a misleading argument**: Your proposal involves adding default methods. That just wasn't on the table back then.

In the end what you want is 'almost, but not entirely, backwards compatible'. Oracle/Java Lang Architects tend to say that 'java does not break backwards compatibility' but this is a gross oversimplification and a borderline lie. If you ask a little further they will eventually admit that this is not true: The heart of the matter is that java weighs the cost of any backwards break (how likely is it, and what happens to code that did break it? If it silently still compiles and runs but does the wrong thing, that's horrible, if it is a trivial update that a refactor script can automatically apply every time, that's great - and then mix in the odds any given codebase stumbles on it, and you have an idea of 'cost'), vs the benefit of it.

The costs are *very minor* here. It is extremely unlikely any code base would break. However, if you want to actually propose this feature, it would help a lot to do some research and try to think of any library (or if you can't, look at the top 100 lists which various folks blog about, analysing e.g. github java projects as source material) to go through a bunch to try to see if the thing that happened with `.isEmpty` would happen with these methods.

Then, there is some bad news: Proposing a java feature is exceedingly unlikely to succeed. For some perspective, as author of Project Lombok, someone who's spend many hundreds of hours reading mailing lists like lambda-dev, who has contributed a large part of the actual lambda syntax and conceptual basis, and has held conversations with multiple Java Language Architects at some length (mostly at java conferences), I've sent in a proposal which included a full patch for java itself, and all due updates needed for the JLS, which didn't break backwards compatibility at all, and it never got anywhere. Not even so much as a JEP.

Last time I spoke to an Oracle engineer they did promise that things are a little bit better now, but that doesn't go particularly far: I don't know of any java feature around or on the horizon that was sourced by an outsider that got kicked straight to a JEP and got anywhere near the foreseeable horizon of java features in the past 10 years. From time to time someone (usually Joe Darcy or Alex Buckley) runs a project to 'add a bunch of small  convenient language changes', such as [Project Coin](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/coin/) (that was 11 years ago, oof). The second take on this is [Project Amber](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/amber/), which I think is meant to be a more continuous project vs. coin which had a specific short-lived timespan.

The route to get this into java would presumably go through amber.

Comment: Again, never did I say `SortedMap` should be applied to every `Map` implementation. You have twisted my Answer in an utterly wrong interpretation. Please retract.

Comment: Your answer is still fundamentally misleading, but for an entirely different reason (yes, I misread the first time). Answer has been edited to reflect this.

Comment: I don't think that answers should be used to attack other answers to be honest; if you think that things can be improved you can use the comments section (and I guess you already did that). Besides that, you've already indicated that you were wrong about the initial attack, but the text still seems to include it.

Comment: @MAartenBodewes no, the text has been updated, and the argument uses reasoning and falsifiable information to make its case. Treating it as an attack on a person - that's in your head, not in this answer. At no point does it impinge on Basil Bourque's credibility or character. It merely trashes his argument (using falsifiables). Don't invent personal slights where none exist.

Answer (score 2):

As [commented by Johannes Kuhn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65866573/would-it-be-possible-to-add-default-methods-to-comparable-without-breaking-java#comment116456030_65866573), [Stuart Marks documented a case](https://stuartmarks.wordpress.com/2020/09/22/incompatibilities-with-jdk-15-charsequence-isempty/) where adding the [`CharSequence.isEmpty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/CharSequence.html#isEmpty()) default method to Java 15 broke a third-party library.

So, given the historic priority to make newer versions of Java maximally [backward-compatible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_compatibility) with existing apps, the better approach is to define a new interface. The new interface would introduce your new methods. In theory the old interface might eventually, after a very long time, be marked deprecated to suggest phasing out the old for the new. In the meantime, existing code would not be disturbed while new code could take advantage of the new ideas.

This was done, for example, in the [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) interface. The sub-interface [`SortedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedMap.html) arrived with Java 1.2 (a.k.a. Java 2). Years later, in Java 6, came the idea to extend that interface with additional methods. But revising `SortedMap` runs the risk of disturbing existing implementations within the bundled Java libraries as well as breaking third-party implementations. So they chose to instead define a new interface [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html). They made the newer interface `NavigableMap` a sub-interface of `SortedMap`.

`NavigableMap` is really just the “2.0” version of `SortedMap`. As far as I know, there is no reason why any implementation would not want to support the larger suite of methods rather than the fewer found in `SortedMap`. So, sure, it would be nice to have had only a single such interface rather than two, but *c’est la vie*.

Here is a graphic table I made showing the various implementations of the `Map` interface bundled with Java 11. You can see how the interfaces `SortedMap` and `NavigableMap` live side-by-side.

[image: Table of map implementations in Java 11, comparing their features]

I wholeheartedly support your idea of effectively extending `Comparable` with those particular methods (good naming, too, btw). But I believe your proposal would only fly as a new sub-interface of `Comparable`.

Comment: Thanks, probably should have been `lessThan` to be honest. Now for a name for the new `Comparable`...

Comment: The part in this answer about SortedMap is dead wrong, though. Any comparator in existence can gain, for free, the `atMost` method. It is, indeed, a default method. Contrast to SortedMap: Not all maps are sorted; methods like 'headMap' cannot be (sensibly) written in a default manner so that they work for all existing map interfaces. The task that headMap does, is fundamentally inefficient for e.g. HashMap, the most commonly used map impl.

Comment: Default methods weren't available in Java 6, which is immediately relevant.

Comment: @rzwitserloot I was not ever talking about applying to `SortedMap` to all `Map` implementations. My Answer is about the relationship between `SortedMap` and `NavigableMap`. Please show me where I discussed applying to all `Map` implementations so I might fix that part.

Comment: Yes, this is unfortunate. I misread your comment but there is a different fundamental issue with your answer now: NavigableMap was created when `default` methods didn't exist, and that makes the SortedMap/NavigableMap issue almost entirely irrelevant to this question. This answer remains misleading and draws the wrong conclusion, even if it does start out linking to useful resources.

Comment: Although that about the default methods may be true, I do think that extending an interface can still lead to conflicts, default method or not a default method. So "misleading" is taking it a bit too far if you ask me.