# Why does using a method reference generate an inner class in byte code?

Tags: java, jvm, inner-classes

I wrote simple example of using method reference:

```
public class Main {
private static String identity(String param) {
    return param;
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    Function<String, String> fun = Main::identity;
    System.out.println(fun.apply("Hello"));
}}
```

And in generated byte code is **InnerClass**:

```
InnerClasses:
 public static final #68= #67 of #71; //Lookup=class java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup of class java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles
BootstrapMethods:
0: #35 invokestatic java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.metafactory:(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;
Method arguments:
  #36 (Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;....
```

I supposed this innerClass is used in lambda bootstrap method, but I do not know when jvm create object of this class and what information will be store in object of this class. Could anyone explain it to me?

Comment: No object is created because your method is `static`. I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I think OP is talking about the `fun` object?

Comment: I wondered what is this inner class and why compiler generated it. If I see "InnerClasses" in byte code I supposed that jvm eventually create object of this class.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002380/why-are-java-8-lambdas-invoked-using-invokedynamic. Lambdas can possibly be converted into anonymous classes that are a type of inner class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not a generated inner class, but rather `InnerClasses` attribute specified in [JVMS §4.7.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.6). The specification requires that this attribute lists every class (referenced in the constant pool) that is not a member of a package.

Basically, `javac` generates `InnerClasses` attribute for all inner classes it sees in the code. E.g.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (Map.Entry e : Collections.emptyMap().entrySet()) {

        }
    }
}
```

The bytecode for above class will refer to `Map.Entry` as an inner class of `Map`:

```
InnerClasses:
   public static #31= #7 of #23; //Entry=class java/util/Map$Entry of class java/util/Map
```

In JDK lambdas are implemented with [`invokedynamic`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokedynamic) instruction. According to the specification, resolution of `invokedynamic` involves calling a bootstrap method with 4 arguments of the following types:

1. [`MethodHandle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html)
2. [`MethodHandles.Lookup`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.Lookup.html)
3. `String`
4. `MethodType`

Java Runtime creates these objects internally, but since the bytecode refers to `MethodHandles.Lookup` class, `javac` generates `InnerClasses` attribute for it.

Comment: That part of §4.7.6 annoys me for years now… Why does *every* class have to redundantly repeat the information about inner class relations of referenced classes. I can’t imagine any actual use case for that information, as no-one would consider consulting the byte code of `Test` to find out whether `Map.Entry` is a nested type.