# Java Generic Singleton Factory Pattern

Tags: java, generics, singleton

I am having a stump of a time understanding the condundrum below. Here is a code snippet that compiles, yet throws the exception

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
    TestGenericSingleton$$Lambda$1/303563356 cannot be cast to 
    TestGenericSingleton$IntegerConsumer
        at TestGenericSingleton.main(TestGenericSingleton.java:23)
```

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class TestGenericSingleton 
{
    static final Consumer<Object> NOOP_SINGLETON = t -> {System.out.println("NOOP Consumer accepting " + t);};
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    static <R extends Consumer<T>, T> R noopConsumer() 
    {
        return (R)NOOP_SINGLETON;
    }
    
    static interface IntegerConsumer extends Consumer<Integer> {};
    
    public static void main(String[] argv) 
    {
        Consumer<Boolean> cb = noopConsumer();
        cb.accept(true);
        
        IntegerConsumer ic = t -> {System.out.println("NOOP Consumer2 accepting " + t);} ;
        ic.accept(3);
        
        ic = noopConsumer();
        ic.accept(3);
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

What stumps me is that the Java compiler can generate a proper IntegerConsumer-compatible object out of the lambda on line 20, yet the previously constructed non-generic lambda constructed as the singleton on line 8 can not be used. Is that because the lambda on line 20 has a reifiable subtype of the Consumer that fits the type of the IntegerConsumer reference immediately, whereas the lambda that is cast on line 10 can not be cast at runtime to a real subtype of Consumer ? But then shouldn't the generic bounded type declaration on line 8 take care of that? Any help is really appreciated !

Comment: Because you have a cast, the compiler can't do its job. It knows that the inner class generated at line 20 needs to implement IntegerConsumer, so it does. It has no way of making there inner class generated at line 5 do so. But perhaps I misunderstand your question?

Comment: I think the reason is obvious. Comsumer<Object> is not a subtype of Comsumer<Integer>, of course it can not be casted.

Answer (score 0):

> the previously constructed non-generic lambda constructed as the singleton on line 8 can not be used

We will remove lambda and understand the root cause of the exception. Let's consider the below simpler example.

```
public class TestGenericObject {

    static final Object NOOP_SINGLETON = new Object();

    static <R extends Object> R noopConsumer() {
        return (R) NOOP_SINGLETON;
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        Object cb = noopConsumer();
        Integer ic = noopConsumer(); // Throws java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    }
}
```

The exception is justified. NOOP_SINGLETON's actual type is Object but we are trying to cast it to Integer. This would be same as trying, `Integer ic = (Integer) new Object()`. In your case, for the same reason you cannot cast `Consumer<Object>` type to `IntegerConsumer`.

---

One interesting observation is the exception is not thrown within the `noopConsumer()` and is rather thrown in the `main()`.
Below is the output of `javap -v -c` for the method `noopConsumer`

```
... // Removed lines for clarity
 static <R extends java.lang.Object> R noopConsumer();
    ...
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=0, args_size=0
         0: getstatic     #2                  // Field NOOP_SINGLETON:Ljava/lang/Object;
         3: areturn
```

You can see there is no op code present for casting. But for the `main()`

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=3, args_size=1
         0: invokestatic  #3                  // Method noopConsumer:()Ljava/lang/Object;
         3: astore_1
         4: invokestatic  #3                  // Method noopConsumer:()Ljava/lang/Object;
         7: checkcast     #4                  // class java/lang/Integer
        10: astore_2
        11: return
```

at this line `7:checkcast #4`, it checks if returned type is of Integer. This behaviour is due to 2 reasons

1. In `noopConsumer()`, the tighter bound of R is Object and NOOP_SINGLETON is of type Object as well. Hence, post type erasure, the casting is redundant and removed.
2. The reason `main()` has a cast check is again due to [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). As mentioned in the link, if required, type casting will be inserted during type erasure.

---

Back to Lambdas. Lambdas use `invokedynamic` opcode to generate code at runtime. [This](https://www.baeldung.com/java-invoke-dynamic) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30002627/4158037) are excellent resources to understand better about lambda handling at runtime.
For the below code,

```
public static void main(String[] argv) {
        Consumer<Object> NOOP_SINGLETON = t -> {System.out.println("NOOP Consumer accepting " + t);};
        TestGenericSingleton.IntegerConsumer ic = t -> {System.out.println("NOOP Consumer2 accepting " + t);} ;
    }
```

lets analyse the byte code.

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
   ...
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=3, args_size=1
         0: invokedynamic #2,  0              // InvokeDynamic #0:accept:()Ljava/util/function/Consumer;
         5: astore_1
         6: invokedynamic #3,  0              // InvokeDynamic #1:accept:()Lcom/TestGenericSingleton$IntegerConsumer;
        11: astore_2
        12: return
```

The `invokedynamic` passes 2 different expected types `Ljava/util/function/Consumer` and `()Lcom/TestGenericSingleton$IntegerConsumer` to [LambdaMetafactory.metafactory()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html#metafactory-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.Lookup-java.lang.String-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-).
So though the code `t -> {System.out.println("NOOP Consumer accepting " + t);}` within the lambdas are same, they are 2 different types.

---

To **summarize**, the lambdas are built at runtime and the returned instance will have the type specified in the declaration. Hence, NOOP_SINGLETON is of type `Consumer` and ic is of type `IntegerConsumer`. Casting from type `Consumer` to `IntegerConsumer` will fail for the same reason, `Integer ic = (Integer)new Object()` fails.

Comment: Thank you so much for the wonderful explanation! I really appreciate the time you took to answer this.

Comment: @AlexanderShenker, Cheers. Happy to have answered your first question in SO