# Implements Listener Directly or Implements on Class (Performance)

Tags: android, performance

Is there a difference on performance between this two situations:

## Situation 1

```
this.pathSelect = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mainactivity_path_select);
    this.pathSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // do my work
        }
    });
```

## Situation 2

```
    private class PathSelectClick implements View.OnClickListener
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // do my work
        }
    }

    this.pathSelect = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mainactivity_path_select);
    this.pathSelect.setOnClickListener(new PathSelectClick());
```

For visual i like use the  situation 2, is this bad? Thanks, all!

Comment: no there is not performance difference

Comment: Number 2 has the advantage of being reusable (apply same listener to multiple buttons) without duplicating the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is almost no performance difference. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028341/java-anonymous-class-efficiency-implications). But if there would be a slightly micro difference, your favorite version would be slightly faster.

Answer (score 1):

There is no performance difference

In the first situatiion you use annonymous inner class and implement the interface `View.OnClickListener`

In the second situation you use a class  `PathSelectClick` which implements the interface.

Check the below to know when to use

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/whentouse.html