# Refactoring - Combine PolygonClickListener and MarkerClickListener

Tags: java, android, google-maps, listener, readability

I am trying to refactor the following method by removing the duplicates in both `map.setOnPolygonClickListener` and `map.setOnMarkerClickListener`.

Both listeners do exactly the same thing and I would like to combine them as one but since the call comes from different objects (`Marker` or `Polygon`), I am not sure how to combine them.

```
public class NavigationFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    OnCameraIdleListener, Subject, SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, SearchView.OnCloseListener 
{

    /**
    * add markers and polygons overlay for each building
    */

    private void addBuildingMarkersAndPolygons() {
        List<Building> allBuildings = new ArrayList<>();
        allBuildings.addAll(Campus.SGW.getBuildings());
        allBuildings.addAll(Campus.LOY.getBuildings());

        for (Building building : allBuildings) {
            createBuildingMarkersAndPolygonOverlay(building);
        }

        map.setOnPolygonClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnPolygonClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onPolygonClick(Polygon polygon) {
                setBottomSheetContent(polygon);
                setupOriginAndDestinationForOutdoorDirection(polygon);
            }
          });

       map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                setBottomSheetContent(marker);
                setupOriginAndDestinationForOutdoorDirection(marker);
                return true;
           }
       });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I intended to write this as a comment, but was too long.
May be I do not understand the question properly, Marker and Polygon has no common parent. I guess, if you make a nested class, i.e

```
private class PolygonAndMarkerClickListener implements GoogleMap.OnPolygonClickListener, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener{

        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            //your code
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPolygonClick(Polygon polygon) {
            //your code
        }
    }
```

then

```
PolygonAndMarkerClickListener polygonAndMarkerClickListener = new PolygonAndMarkerClickListener();
        map.setOnPolygonClickListener(polygonAndMarkerClickListener);
        map.setOnMarkerClickListener(polygonAndMarkerClickListener);
```

This will reduce some overhead, and also looks pretty good.

If you want to make a single method so that could be called from both the listeners, then you have to use "instanceOf", which according to many senior developers should be avoided. I guess generics won't be of much help here.

Comment: I don't see how will such a code reduce some overhead, I actually would argue that It would increase complexity! So yeah first of all polygons and markers are not related what so ever so you can't really listen to both events but how does creating a click listeners for both reduce overhead could you please elaborate.

Plus it would be actually better to create it as an interface and then add the impl don't you think ?

Comment: My mistake for using the term "overhead", but please do care to see this answer, though it is arguable. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3028371/5689605
And can you please elaborate your last line "it would be actually better to create it as an interface and then add the impl don't you think"

Comment: Okay so this can be arguable but in a very limited cases where you actually have more than one usage for those two different listeners! but I can't see that here, its actually a one time use and won't probably happen again plus the fact that the functionality is the actual repeated element and not the listening process, Please see my answer.
what I meant by it would actually be better to create an interface is that instead of directly implementing the class, use a program to interface approach. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992384/program-to-an-interface-what-does-it-mean

Comment: Great answer. I guess, it is a part of SOLID principles. It is also recommended for MVP architecture. But, if you see the question, you will find that here there is no separate module for Google map, and even the logic implementation is done in the fragment itself. Thus I thought, this would be apt here. I may be wrong. By the way, I am trying to build up a Google map module for helping out on the purpose. You can look at the project and suggest edits.
https://github.com/itsdebs/MapEasy

Answer (score 1):

Okay so from what I see I don't think there is a good reason to do so, of-course you can do the above and add an extra `class` to `listen` to both events but that didn't really solve the problem in-fact it will increase complexity from my point of view.

I would do such a thing like a one listener when both `objects` are related some how but there is no relation between `Polygons` and `Markers` what so ever, in fact the only similar code in your case is the functionality that both `Listeners` have and not the actual `listening` event so a one `class` or `interface` that `implement/extends` both won't really add a real value as the only consumption for both will happen this one time, hope that make sense! and in such a case where the event is similar and the `Object` can't be decided until run time, you can use [Factory Design Pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm) but there is no need here to do so!

Now `Polygons` and `Markers` both have different listeners and they are not related what so ever so if we agree on that what you really are looking for here is a way to shorten your code and make it more readable, in this case:

**1**-Combine both `setBottomSheetContent(polygon);` and `setupOriginAndDestinationForOutdoorDirection(polygon);` If possible and if there is a real general purpose for both methods, if not keep them as they are!

**2**-Use Lambda:

So if you are using Java 8 you probably heard of lambda and you actually can use it in such a situation instead of Anonymous inner classes:

```
map.setOnPolygonClickListener(polygon -> {yourCompinedMethod; return true;});
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(marker -> {yourCompinedMethod; return true;});
```